# Julia Plot mesh with labeled faces

Tags: matplotlib, plot, julia, ijulia-notebook, gadfly

I have a triangular mesh encoded as

- `3 x M` `vertices` matrix, whose each column represents vertex of 3d mesh object
- `3 x N` `faces` matrix, whose each column is a set of 3 column indices of `vetrices` that define a triangle
- `N` length vector of labels (some number) for each of the faces

My question is how can to plot this mesh with labeled faces (meaning label should be located on the face itself, **not** as a legend on the side)?

Comment: Using gadfly or pyplot or plots.jl? Easier to help if you specify a package and also some code to show what you've tried so far would be good too :)

Comment: Either of Gadfly.jl or Plots.jl is fine. Don't know where to start to be honest...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that in Plots, sorry.